# Mutating vector elements in HashMap<String, Vec<&mut String>>

Tags: rust

I've boiled a problem I'm seeing down to this [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=30a92de17628830787b9862bfc548341):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn process(mut inputs: Vec<String>) -> Vec<String> {

    // keep track of duplicate entries in the input Vec
    let mut duplicates: HashMap<String, Vec<&mut String>> = HashMap::new();
    for input in &mut inputs {
        duplicates.entry(input.clone())                                                                               
                  .or_insert_with(|| Vec::new())                                                                      
                  .push(input);
    }
    
    // modify the input vector in place to append the number of each duplicate
    for (key, instances) in duplicates {
        for (i, instance) in instances.iter().enumerate() {
            *instance = format!("{}_{}", instance, i);
        }
    }
    
    return inputs;
}

fn main() {
    println!("results: {:?}", process(vec![
        String::from("test"),
        String::from("another_test"),
        String::from("test")
    ]));
}
```

I would expect this to print something like `results: test_0, another_test_0, test_1` but am instead running into build issues:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:13:25
   |
13 |             *instance = format!("{}_{}", instance, i);
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `&mut String`, found struct `String`
   |
```

I'm still a bit new to rust and so haven't really found anything online that has helped. I'm hoping that I'm doing something silly. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```rust
for (key, instances) in duplicates {
    for (i, instance) in instances.iter().enumerate() {
        *instance = format!("{}_{}", instance, i);
    }
}
```

`for (key, instances) in duplicates` invokes the `IntoIterator` trait on `HashMap<String, Vec<&mut String>>`, with

```rust
type Item = (String, Vec<&mut String>);
```

so `instances: Vec<&mut String>`.<sup>1</sup>  `instances.iter()` then produces references to the elements of `instances`, so `instance: &&mut String`.  So `instance` would need to be dereferenced twice in order to access the element in `inputs`, which, unfortunately, doesn't actually work:

```rust
error[E0594]: cannot assign to `**instance` which is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/main.rs:14:13
   |
13 |         for (i, instance) in instances.iter().enumerate() {
   |                 -------- help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut &mut String`
14 |             **instance = format!("{}_{}", instance, i);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^ `instance` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be written
```

The problem is that we are not allowed to modify the `T` value behind `&&mut T`.  Here's the reason: immutable references can be freely copied, so there may be multiple `&&mut T` instances pointing to the same `&mut T`, defeating the anti-aliasing property of `&mut`.

Therefore, we have to change the type of `instance` to `&mut &mut String`, by using `mut` and `.iter_mut()`:

```rust
for (key, mut instances) in duplicates {
    for (i, instance) in instances.iter_mut().enumerate() {
        **instance = format!("{}_{}", instance, i);
    }
}
```

Since `key` isn't needed, we can use [`.values_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.values_mut), so that `instances` itself becomes an `&mut`:

```rust
for instances in duplicates.values_mut() {
    for (i, instance) in instances.iter_mut().enumerate() {
        **instance = format!("{}_{}", instance, i);
    }
}
```

<sup>1</sup> We'll use `var: type` to denote that `var` is of type `type`.

---

In general, references (especially mutable ones) stored in containers are tedious to work with, so I recommend an alternative approach: (with an in-place interface for simplicity)

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, fmt::Write};

fn process(texts: &mut Vec<String>) {
    let mut counter = HashMap::<String, usize>::new();

    for text in texts.iter_mut() {
        let count = counter.entry(text.clone()).or_insert(0);
        write!(text, "_{}", count).unwrap();
        *count += 1;
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e594c430e5b1cb13ea2a8e3cf39ce083))

Answer (score 2):

Iterating returns you references over the values stored in your map's vecs.

As your map's vecs contain references to start with, you have to dereference twice, using `**`.

You also need to use `iter_mut` when iterating if you want to change the content.

All in one, you can change your loop like this:

```rust
for (key, instances) in duplicates.iter_mut() {
    for (i, instance) in instances.iter_mut().enumerate() {
        **instance = format!("{}_{}", instance, i);
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ba79c8fe10b2bfb42f3ea8675bad92c6)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is that *immutability is transitive*.

That is, coming from other languages you might expect that a `& &mut Foo` would let you dereference the outer ref', access the inner mutable ref, and update the `Foo` based on that. However if you consider the purpose of rust's unique references, this would be the same as allowing multiple mutable references: take a mutable reference, create any number of immutable references to it, and any holder of one such would be able to modify the original object, concurrently.

Therefore that's not acceptable. All references in a chain must be unique (`&mut`) in order to get mutable access to what's at the end of the chain, and so you need to `instances.iter_mut()`, and dereference twice (otherwise you're assigning to the `&mut String` at the first level, not the inner `String`), and for that you need `instances` itself to be mutable:

```rust
    for (_, mut instances) in duplicates {
        for (i, instance) in instances.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            **instance = format!("{}_{}", instance, i);
        }
    }
```

alternatively since you don't care about `duplicates`' keys:

```rust
    for instances in duplicates.values_mut() {
        for (i, instance) in instances.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            **instance = format!("{}_{}", instance, i);
        }
    }
```